# Replicate standard community components

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

I am attempting to style and brand a new Community Help Centre, and while the premade templates and components provide the functionality I'm after, they have no ability for visual customising to get what I'm after.

My first thought was to D.I.Y some LWC components to replicate all the functionality - starting with the very basics of knowledge article search, article detail page, topic listing, and topic recommendations - with very hit or miss results.
Querying Knowledge Article data is fine, but anything to do with Topics just seems like a nightmare and the only documentation I can find is using ConnectApi (eg., getTopics()).

My other option if that fails is to just write a whole bunch of overriding CSS styles to make the premade components look a bit nicer....not my preferred option!

Is there anyway to find the code for the pre-made components for me to leverage and build from?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for The [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) Components. From that page you should find a lot of component code that should work for you!

Hope that helps.

Comment: I come from Front-End development, so all that is easy and makes sense....but hooking up the backend and actually getting the data I need is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about that! I'd suggest rephrasing your question with more specifics of what you wish to achieve with some examples. It's not possible to answer as written.